# wordpress template reuse id for different page feeds

Tags: wordpress, css, templates, hash, woocommerce

I'm building a wordpress template for a home page that takes an excerpt and the featured image from a category or page and displays a number of them on the page.
Under each there is a link to 'read more' or 'buy'
I am using the woocommerce plugin for the shop element.
Within the posts/pages there is a woocommerce 'add to cart' shortlink to the product. 
I want each 'buy' link on the home page to go the part of the post/page with the shortlink code.
So I used a div id="buy" and then added #buy to the template link.
This works fine once.
I know you are not supposed to reuse an ID. 
However I want the person updating the site with new products not to have to touch the template so I want them to be able to use the same ID.
Each section of the home page is within it's own loop, which is reset each time.
Would this make it okay to reuse the same ID? Throughout the template and on the individual posts/pages??

Comment: Please include a minimal,complete, verifiable example in your question. In other words, include the relevant codes. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the hash #buy in the url on the category page is no problem - you can have it there on as many urls as you want. And if you're creating a `<div id="buy">...</div>` on the individual page, it's no problem and you can have that on however many individual pages you want.

Where you run into trouble is if you have `<div id="buy">...</div>` multiple times on a page because any link to that anchor would only go to the first one on the page.